Can Xと同様 and Xも同様 mean the same thing?
One of the definitions of だって is

特殊（代表的）な場合を例示し、他の場合も同様であるということを表わす。

I am not 100% certain but I think this is one of the unique situations where も in ～も同様 functions like と. This is the same も used in ～も同然. Is that right? Or maybe this kind of も can only be used with 同然?
Kind of related to my previous question: Does Xと同じ and Xも同じ mean the same thing?

Perhaps you should try to translate this sentence into English.  I'm unclear why you think 他の場合も同様 and 他の場合と同様 mean the same thing.  If you translate it here, perhaps we can understand how you're parsing the sentence.

@A.Ellett Both 他の場合と同様である and 他の場合も同様である is understood as "the same as other cases."

However it's understood, the grammatical structure is different.  他の場合と同様である="it is similar to other cases".   他の場合も同様である="other cases are also similar [to it]".

It really seems the answer you link to has already answered this question.

@A.Ellett So you think this も means "too/also." How do you explain も in ～も同然?

も means "too/also".  I'm not sure why you would think it means something different. As @naruto explains in his answer, these things can be similarly rephrased, but that doesn't mean も somehow has a different meaning.  Without any context, I would parse "Aも同然" as "A too is no different".

^ @A.Ellett, ～も同然 is a fixed expression that's quite different from ～も同様, and is used like 太郎は死んだも同然だ(Taro is as good as dead), 花子は会社に殺されたも同然だ(It's as if Hanako was killed by the company), so the も doesn't mean "too/also. Also compare AはBも同然 vs AもBと同様 ✖AはBも同様

@chocolate Thank you for pointing that out.

Aと同様だ and Aも同様だ are quite different:

Aと同様だ means "It's the same as A".
Aも同様だ means "A is (also) the same (as something previously mentioned)".

However, in your context, 他の場合と同様である and 他の場合も同様である happen to work interchangeably. For example, in a sentence like アインシュタインにだって分からない ("Even Einstein cannot understand it"), the following two descriptions equally make sense as an explanation of this だって.

他の場合も(特殊な場合と)同様である
In other cases as well, it's the same as in (Einstein's) extreme case
(特殊な場合も)他の場合と同様である
Even in (Einstein's) extreme case, it's the same as in other cases


Thank you again! So following your logic, something like 死んだも同然 can be understood as 死んだのもそれと同然?

@weeab00 No. 同然 and 同様 are quite different, and それと同然 makes almost no sense to me.
